# How can I follow the merge history of a specific git commit?

Tags: git

Recently we deployed a new build to production but when unit tests were ran against it we found that an expected output was not updated. Right now the general theory around the office is that the code was not properly merged from development to QA to production and I've been tasked with determining if that is the case.

I've been able to isolate the commit to development:

```
user@workstation /c/Projects/major-project (master)
$ git log --grep=ABC-1234
commit 33a27eeddffd50fe2ab9ea8ee5eb806ae18102fd
Author: author
Date:   Mon May 19 13:34:49 2014 -0400

    ABC-1234 Updated the output to match new format.

user@workstation /c/Projects/major-project (master)
$
```

But now that it is there a way I can generate a list of the branches that it has been merged into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `git branch` with the `--contains` option, e.g.:

```
$ git branch --contains 33a27ee
* master
  development
```

From [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch):

> With `--contains`, shows only the branches that contain the named commit (in other words, the branches whose tip commits are descendants of the named commit).